# How to create a new vector with particular columns from existing 2D vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have 2D Vector (`vector<vector<string>>`) with a lot of columns (m*n) (Here I mentioned this 2D Vector as Maintable). I want to create a new vector with a few particular columns from main table. 
For Example, Suppose If I have a main table with 12 columns, I want to take any 3 Non Contiguous columns from the main table into new 2D Vector. How to do that?

Comment: Please share the definitions, I'm not sure how you those *columns* get represented in your `std::vector` (because is a `std::vector`,is it?)

Comment: What is the 2D Vector?!

Comment: If you have the option, such an operation would be much easier using `std::slice` and `std::valarray`. If not, consider having your data be a single `std::vector<string>` and then you can simply use some simple indexing math to present it as though it were a 2D matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something as the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

//...

const size_t N = 10;
std::string a[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v1( N, std::vector<std::string>( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) ) );
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v2;

v2.reserve( v1.size() );

for ( const std::vector<std::string> &v : v1 )
{
    v2.push_back( std::vector<std::string>(std::next( v.begin(), 2 ), std::next( v.begin(), 5 ) ) );
}

for ( const std::vector<std::string> &v : v2 )
{
    for ( const std::string &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

It is simple to rewrite the code using the C++  2003 syntax. For example you can write

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v1( N, 
                                          std::vector<std::string>( a, a + sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) ) );
```

instead of

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v1( N, std::vector<std::string>( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) ) );
```

and so on.

**EDIT:** If the columns are not adjacent then you can use the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    const size_t M = 3;

    std::string a[N] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v1( N, std::vector<std::string>( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) ) );
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v2;

    v2.reserve( v1.size() );

    std::array<std::vector<std::string>::size_type, M> indices = { 2, 5, 6 };

    for ( const std::vector<std::string> &v : v1 )
    {
        std::vector<std::string> tmp( M );
        std::transform( indices.begin(), indices.end(), tmp.begin(),
            [&]( std::vector<std::string>::size_type i ) { return ( v[i] ); } );
        v2.push_back( tmp );
    }

    for ( const std::vector<std::string> &v : v2 )
    {
        for ( const std::string &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add, this syntax is C++11

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This program is about to get sequence of columns. My Task is to get non contiguous Columns. From 10 columns vector Table, I want to take 2nd, 5th, 6th column.